# "mat-icon" doesn't work in the angular single-spa projects

Tags: angular, angular-material, single-spa, single-spa-angular, mat-icon

I created an angular project from "single-spa" as the library and I implemented angular material inside the project. I used mat-icon but it doesn’t work. it doesn't show anything. And also I use a design kit and I took some components there but again icon doesn't show in the used component. Icon display like this -> [image]

Who can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [document](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview), mat-icon require the icon font to be import in the HTML. To import the font icon, you may refers to https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web